# Replace attachment when uploading a new attachment

Tags: file-upload, save, xpages, xsp

I have a simple form and body field. when user upload an attachment I want to remove any attachment already in the body field of the document. how can I do this in my save button.

I have tried to set the properites on the fileUpload control to always change the filename to tha same name but this does not replace the file, instead it adds a new file and add a new sequential number to it

```
<xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload1" value="#{userdoc.Body}" filename="profile"     seUploadname="false"></xp:fileUpload>
```

I have also tried to loop all embedded attachments in body field before before save, and all attachments are then removed, but my new attachment is not added.

Comment: Deleting attachments before save doesn't work because it has attached the new file at that stage. So you are also deleting the last attached file I guess (you might test it printing attachment names before deleting).

Answer (score 7):

A little late, but in case  anyone gets here just as I did through Google...

There's also another option: a NotesXSPDocument.getAttachmentList("rtitem") returns a list of attachments in the document. Each entry is of type [DominoDocument.AttachmentValueHolder](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/XPagesExtAPI/8.5.2/com/ibm/xsp/model/domino/wrapped/DominoDocument.AttachmentValueHolder.html) which has a getState() property that returns if a file was already in the document or just added. To remove the file that was already in the document you could add this SSJS code to a save button (assuming "files" is the name of the richtext item holding the files):

```
var attList = docFile.getAttachmentList("files");

for(var i=0; i<attList.size(); i++) {
  var att = attList.get(i);

  if (att.getState()==0) {      //STATE_INDOCUMENT: this is the 'old' file: remove it
    docFile.removeAttachment("files", att.getName() );
  } else if (att.getState()==1) {       //STATE_ADDED: this is the new file
           //leave it           
  } 
}
```

Comment: Nice thx, very usefull.. this works also in the onChange event on the ´xp:fileUpload´.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by removing all attachments first (use the removeAllAttachments function from NotesXSPDocument object) and then attach the uploaded file manually to the richtext item.

This SSJS code has to be added to beforeRenderResponse-event of your XPage / Custom Control:

```
var con = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var request:com.sun.faces.context.MyHttpServletRequestWrapper = con.getRequest();
var map:java.util.Map = request.getParameterMap();
var fileDataName = getClientId('fileUpload1') ;
var fileData:com.ibm.xsp.http.UploadedFile = map.get( fileDataName );
if( fileData == null ){
    return;
}

var tempFile:java.io.File = fileData.getServerFile();
var correctedFile = new java.io.File( tempFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + 
    java.io.File.separator + fileData.getClientFileName() ); 

var success = tempFile.renameTo(correctedFile);
try{
    document1.removeAllAttachments("Body");
}catch(e){}

var rtFiles:NotesRichTextItem = null;
if(!(document1.getDocument().hasItem("Body"))){
    rtFiles = document1.getDocument().createRichTextItem("Body")
}else{
    rtFiles = document1.getDocument().getFirstItem("Body");
} 
rtFiles.embedObject(lotus.domino.local.EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "",
    correctedFile.getAbsolutePath(), null); 
correctedFile.renameTo(tempFile);

document1.save();
```

The richtext item where the files are stored is "Body", the name of the datasource is "document1". The Fileupload control is "fileUpload1".

There are two limitations:

1. You cannot use this with a save button, you have to use a normal button / link which makes a full refresh (see what Serdar Basegmez wrote above)
2. You have to refresh the page after a upload once again, otherwise you will not see the uploaded file in a file download conrol (maybe a partial refresh to this control may work).

**EDIT:**

Sorry, my fault: You **can** use this code above in a submit button that saves the document. Then you **don't** have to refresh the page manually!